# Spring Boot: Add additional config file to the Embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I want to add an additional Configuration File to the embedded Tomcat from Spring Boot.

Normally i would copy the config File to the `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf` folder.
But how can this be done with the embedded Tomcat?

Comment: whatever you wish to do with the config file is possible programatically.

Comment: Check out `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`